# Why the value of parent variable is used instead of value of child variable when the type of the object is child?

Tags: java, variables, polymorphism

```
public class Parent {

    String name = "parent";

    public static class Child extends Parent {
        String name = "child";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        Child c = new Child();
        System.out.println(p.name);   //parent
        System.out.println(c.name);   //child
    }
}
```

There is a rule that the type of the object defines which properties exist in memory.
So my question is why the output of the p.name is 'parent' but not 'child' 
when the type of the p object is Child?

Comment: Methods are inherited, fields are not.

Comment: The JLS says otherwise, "A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces all the non-private fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that are both accessible to code in the class and not hidden by a declaration in the class."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> why the output of the p.name is 'parent' but not 'child' when the type of the p object is Child?

Because ovverriding/polymorphism applies only on methods. Variables still bind to its type. In your case type is Parent, hence you seeing the variable from Parent.

Comment: Inheritance definitely does apply to fields.

Comment: @LewBloch Sorry my bad. Edited. Typed inheritance instead polymorphism

Answer (score 2):

Because defining a field with the same name in the subclass doesn't override the field in the parent class.

Methods are overridable, fields are not.

Here `p.name` refers the `name` of the `Parent` declared type :

```
    Parent p = new Child();
    Child c = new Child();
    System.out.println(p.name);   //parent
```

Comment: properties of class due not  share same memory locations when one class inherits from another.